how to show child object at the bottom parent column
I have a datatable that I want to show a list with another list on it as child. I want to show the child right at the bottom of their parent.
But the code that I use right now make it shown the list of all parent first (after it finish) then show the child.
Can you have any referral to solved problem with same question, or can you help me to show the right way to solve it?
List<DataRow> _buildDataDetail(List<PiutangDetailModel> snapshot) {
    return List.generate(snapshot.length, (index) {
      var data = snapshot[index];
      return DataRow(cells: [
        DataCell(Text(data.ket!)),
        DataCell(Text((data.add)!.toString())),
        DataCell(Text((data.sub)!.toString()))
      ]);
    }, growable: true)
      ..addAll(snapshot.expand((model) {
        return _buildDataBayar(model.piba!);
      }).toList());
  }

  List<DataRow> _buildDataBayar(List<PiutangBayarModel> snapshot) {
    return List.generate(snapshot.length, (index) {
      var data = snapshot[index];
      return DataRow(cells: [
        DataCell(Text(data.ket!)),
        DataCell(Text((0).toString())),
        DataCell(Text((data.total)!.toString()))
      ]);
    });
  }

